# How to get column or selected cell values using objectlistview?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I want to copy the content of selected column or Cells using `objectlistview`.
Currently when I draw selected rectangle using mouse and try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> then it copies the content of  all the selected row's and columns I do not want it.
2ndly I want to add a serial number as header of the row.is object list view
allow or handle it automatically by configuration.

[image: i want to copy only the selected cells values not the entire rows]
if you see the image. if i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> it copies all the 
rows like this:

```
ZAFBGB003YNBGZ6 B003YNBNZ6  $22.61  $22.40  $ -0.21 % -0.93 1   2391817 Good    Acceptable  MERCHANT    21  10
ZAFBNB003YNBNZ6 B003YNBNZ6  $126.69 $22.40  $ -104.29   % -82.32    1   2391817 New Acceptable  MERCHANT    21  10
```

while I want to copy only these values like this.

```
2391817 
2391817
```

Comment: Perhaps, there is some `SelectionMode` property that can be set to `Cells` or `Columns`. Otherwise you will have to look into some copy event handlers of `objectlistview` (if there are any).

Answer (score 0):

If you know which column you want, you can do something simple like this:

```
var olvColumn = olv.GetColumn(6); // whichever column you want
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (object model in olv.SelectedObjects)
    sb.AppendLine(olvColumn.GetStringValue(model));
var selectedCellsAsText = sb.ToString();
```

Now, you can do what you like with `selectedCellsAsText`

Answer (score 0):

As @Eugene suggested, and as you can see there is no selection mode for a list view (it cannot know what type of object you are using), I recommend you to use `DataGridView`, print your object in it and set the `SelectionMode` from the proprieties to `CellSelect`. Then you can achieve what you are looking for.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please, take this only as a reference. Currently I only write code in .NET, not Csharp, but when I read this question, I thought that my code can be helpful for you.

```
Clipboard.Clear()
Dim CurrentSelectedObjects as String = ""
For Each selObject in Me.oListView.SelectedObjects
   CurrentSelectedObjects=CurrentSelectedObjects & CType(selObject, oListFill).GroupName & vbNewLine
Next
Clipboard.SetText(CurrentSelectedObjects)
```

In this .NET code:

- "oListView" is my ObjectListView Object.
- oListFill is my Class for storing my data values as many objects created from this Class. That Class have 3 properties that can be setted, and all of that are of String Type.
- GroupName, is the AspectName that I defined in the OLVColumn Collection Editor and one of the 3 properties of my class (String).

The problem that I cant solve is the use of an Event Handler for catch the CTRL+C key combination for doing that algorithm. The Event Handler that I tried is the same that I use in the past for copying to clipboard the selected subitems of a conventional ListView, but in ObjectListView it don't work (work, ok...but freeze for 30seconds the UI table).

Maybe you can put a button and assign the job execute that procedure.

Again, sorry for putting my .NET idea in a C# question.